# How can I import JavaScript file downloaded from `npm` or `yarn` to client (browser)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am following this tutorial: [Headless Drupal with React](https://medium.com/@Userium/headless-drupal-build-a-drupal-8-api-with-a-reactjs-front-end-e43bf0fb94db). I bet the tutorial itself is not related with my questions. In the tutorial it shows two import of React and ReactDOM from CDN straight in the .html file.

My question is how can I have package manager (`npm` or `yarn`) to download these file to be imported (with RequireJS) to browser, like it is directly taken from CDN? I installed those with this command `yarn add react react-dom`.

My first guess, is that I need to import the two files, `react.js`
 and `react-dom.js` with RequireJS. So, what I have right now in my index.html is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-main="js/main" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my js/main.js I have these simple codes:

```
require(["node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js"]);
require(["node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js"]);
```

But it returns an odd error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react.development.js:12
(anonymous) @ react.development.js:12
react-dom.development.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react-dom.development.js:12
```

**To re-phrase: how can I install React and ReactDOM from package manager and import those files straight into my HTML file?**

I don't bother about best-practice at this moment, I would not accept solution like, "just save the .js files straight from the CDN", ... kind of solutions.

Comment: Okay, but looking from the tutorial, importing the React JavaScript files straight from the CDN __works__. I want to do that, but instead from CDN, I want the JS files downloaded to local with a package manager.

Comment: I don't know what is that.... I am not using NodeJS as a server. The React will be used as a Drupal theme.

Comment: What are you using for a server?

Comment: I suppose that does not matter since I can import ReactJS from CDN without any server at all. But if this is actually matter, I go with PHP7.0 and Apache2.

Comment: But importing like this works: https://i.imgur.com/TqEUN1T.png. Why would I need to use server?

Comment: My only guess is that the two js files are different in your node modules folder then whats in the CDN. They are specifically designed to be ran in a module environment, as the CDN are not. Place the CDN files in the node modules folder with different names and reference them. But I believe there are fundamental differences from the research I have done

Answer (score 0):

```
"<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>"
```

Either use the actual CDN, and download locally to server and then have it on included on your web page. Or you can use a package bundler "A bundler, such as webpack or Browserify. It lets you write modular code and bundle it together into small packages to optimize load time." https://webpack.js.org/ http://browserify.org/ The npm module file is different from the CDN and is not configured to work as a CDN. That is my official answer, and from the research I have done I stand behind it 100%. The link to the image you provided also shows an older version of react, 15 so you might have versioning issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, you can't. At least from what ReactJS provided out-of-the-box. ReactJS downloaded from currently package manager (Yarn or NPM) need a server to run. At the most basic simple HTTP server like `python3 -m http.server` works.

Without CDN, there is no simple way to get ReactJS working with just double clicking HTML file.